# OpenId providers

Tags: java, openid, single-sign-on

Recently I was looking for OpenId provider based on java. we tested OpenAM as our  authentication and authorization provider.

The installation seemed to be easy and the services it provided looked promising.

Unfortunately we found out that Open AM isn't free for commercial use.

We looked into real open source commercial openId solutions.

We found two popular: Josso/Crowd.

Anyone had any experience with them?

Would be great if you could share your technical experience

- Installation, authorization, authentication, community support.

Thanks,
ray.

Comment: Are you looking for a library or a product?

Comment: Actually I am open to both solutions as long as they deliver. My requirements are pretty common: SSO, authentication and roles authorization server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard open source AIM product in academia is Shibboleth (http://shibboleth.net/).  It's a mature and powerful product that's in use all over the world.  It normally uses SAML but there's an OpenID extension.

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdP+OpenID+Configuration

However I'll warn you, configuring can be a chore ime.  I've not used the OpenID extension myself.

Comment: i heard about shibboleth, but is it a product or library? and what about community support? I would like to have some real experienced suggestions.

Comment: It's a set of products with a very active community.  Most UK universities use it to provide identities and most of the large academic publishers use it to protect their content.  It's been around in active development for years. Again I have to say I've not used the OpenId extension.

Comment: Have you ever heard about Josso?

Comment: I haven't, sorry.  My AIM work was mainly in the academic world.